# How to upload images using an API Key that gives you permission to upload? [Python source code included]

Tags: c#, python, api, imgur

The documentation of the API shows source code on how to accomplish this in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pycurl

c = pycurl.Curl()
values = [
          ("key", "YOUR_API_KEY"),
          ("image", (c.FORM_FILE, "file.png"))]
# OR:     ("image", "http://example.com/example.jpg"))]

c.setopt(c.URL, "http://imgur.com/api/upload.xml")
c.setopt(c.HTTPPOST, values)

c.perform()
c.close()
```

I'd like a bit of guidance on how to do this in C#. For instance, I'm lost on what these "values" would be in C#, how would I even declare them?

I'm not familiar with cURL at all, so that might be holding me back from translating a bit.

Help me Obi-wan. You're my only hope. /click

Comment: That python code appears to be using CURL. Look up the documentation for the C# version of the library.

Comment: The documentation for the library is horrible. Also, when trying to add the .dll file to my solution in Visual C# Express 2010 I get an error that the file isn't a Proper COM Component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to perform an HTTP POST, e.g. [this code](http://en.csharp-online.net/HTTP_Post) with a "parameters" string of `key=YOUR_API_KEY&image=http://example.com/example.jpg` or the like.

Comment: I'm a bit confused do you literally put that string as the method's parameter?

Comment: `dopost(@"http://foo.bar", @"key=YOUR_API_KEY&image=http://example.com/example.jpg")` or the like (you don't _need_ the `@` signs here, but as you don't want escape sequences processed, I guess you might as well use them;-).